# why ng-disabled does not work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

This is my html tag:

```
<input class="editable-input" ng-model="ac.accesses.permision.alias" ng-disabled="true">
```

but input tag does not disable.

Comment: @HosseinAkbarzadeh Take  a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-disabled` will work fine either if you missed out input `type`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnkt2khh/)**

```
  <input type="text" class="editable-input" ng-model="ac.accesses.permision.alias" ng-disabled="true">
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sa0gbt87/)**

```
   <input class="editable-input" ng-model="ac.accesses.permision.alias" ng-disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

You must insert `type="text"` in your `input` tag or delete the class.